# Delphi/IOS How to correctly use imp_implementationWithBlock?

Tags: ios, delphi

In IOS I have this function :

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler __IOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __TVOS_AVAILABLE(10.0) __WATCHOS_AVAILABLE(3.0);
```

my particular problem is this param :

```
withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler
```

i translate it like

```
procedure userNotificationCenterWillPresentNotificationWithCompletionHandler(center: UNUserNotificationCenter;
                                                                             willPresentNotification: UNNotification;
                                                                             withCompletionHandler: pointer);
var aImp: procedure(self: pointer; _cmd: pointer; const options); cdecl;
    aOptions: UNNotificationPresentationOptions;
begin

  @aImp := imp_implementationWithBlock(withCompletionHandler);
  aOptions := UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert;
  aImp(self, nil, aOptions);
  imp_removeBlock(@aImp);

end;
```

but it's not work ! i thing i do something wrong when passing the **options**

i declare the imp function like

```
var aImp: procedure(self: pointer; _cmd: pointer; const options); cdecl;
aOptions := UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert;
```

but maybe not the good way, i try to declare it like

```
var aImp: procedure(self: pointer; _cmd: pointer; options: pointer); cdecl;
aOptions := pointer(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);
```

or like

```
var aImp: procedure(self: pointer; _cmd: pointer; options: nsuinteger); cdecl;
aOptions := UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert;
```

none work :( any idea(s) of what I miss ?

Answer (score 1):

a little crazy how i found it (trying all the possible and impossible combinations) but i found it !

```
var aImp: procedure(options: nsuinteger); cdecl;
```

yes simple like this ...

Comment: This seems to be in contradiction to Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418587-imp_implementationwithblock?language=objc, but I'm glad you found the answer!